# OpenGL/Glut: light position is inverted compared to what is declared

Tags: c, opengl, glut, mesh, light

I'm writing a excercise in OpenGL/GLUT on my Mac OS X Yosemite and I have to set the light position after drawing an object with a mesh. At the beginning I declare:

```
lightPos[0] =  0.60;
lightPos[1] =  0.50;
lightPos[2] =  2.20;
lightPos[3] =  0;
```

Then, the following is what I do in my display() function after drawing the mesh:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos );

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(lightPos[0], lightPos[1], lightPos[2]);
    glutSolidSphere(0.1, 12, 12);
glPopMatrix();

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

The thing is that the yellow circle is displayed in the right position according to lightPos array but the real light position is at the inverse values: -0.60, -0.50, -2.20
I don't understand why this happens. Maybe OpenGL/GLUT implementation for Mac OS X have a "strange" implementation?

**UPDATE**
Setting lightPos[3] =-1 it works, I don't know why. Someone said that 4-th dimension of lightPos is the direction, I don't know why it should be set with -1. Now yellow cyrcle and light position agree but if I move the pig beyond the light, then the shadow on the pig and the light side do not agree anymore. See the 2 screenshots:

[image][image]

Comment: Are you aware that you have a directional light (`lightPos[3] = 0`) and not a point light? How have you verified that the "real light position" is wrong?

Comment: No...I'm not aware. I don't even know why there is a 4th dimension in lightPos :(

Comment: Then set it to `1` for now.

Comment: Ok, I've just tried to set the 4-th dimension to -1 and now it works. The light position agrees with the yellow circle. But I don't know why this works...

Comment: a 4D vector is used to describe the position of a light. The vector has values x, y, z, and w.  If w is 1.0, you are defining a light at a point in space. I am not sure how "-1" is working.

Comment: I'm afraid this is fault of our Mac OS X implementation because for our mates using Linux it works with w=1.0...

Comment: Great question. ;) One more thing: Change glTranslate**d** to glTranslate. What if you instead of glTranslate(lightPos[0], lightPos[1], lightPos[2]); type glTranslated(0.60, 0.50, 2.20); , same result ?

Comment: glTranlate does not exists and the linker gets angry. I just have glTranslated and glTranslatef

Comment: ".. following is what I do in my display() function **after** drawing the mesh .."  so I understand from this that (1) you draw the mesh, (2) set and enable light. Should this not be the other way around?

Comment: yes, first I draw and then I enable light. Isn't this correct? I've also tried to invert the two things but nothing changes...I don't know where I am wrong...

Comment: NB: w=-1 would just symmetrize the location. w=weight, 3Dpos = (x,y,z)/w

Comment: ...ok, but still I'm not understanding why with w=1.0 the position of the yellow sphere and the real position of the light source are opposite....

Comment: @LoryLory: what makes you so sure that they are opposite? Maybe your normals are just wrongly oriented.

Comment: Because if the yellow sphere is the space where, for example, x is > 0 then instead the object is illuminated where X is < 0...the same is for y and z coordinates